# Showing derivative vanishes between two points

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is continuous with continous derivatives. Prove that the derivative of

$$ F(x) = \left| \begin{matrix} f(x) & x & 1 \\ f(x_1) & x_1 & 1 \\ f(x_2) & x_2 & 1 \end{matrix} \right| $$

vanishes at some point between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Well, notice that

$$ F(x_1) = \left| \begin{matrix} f(x_1) & x_1 & 1 \\ f(x_1) & x_1 & 1 \\ f(x_2) & x_2 & 1 \end{matrix} \right| = 0 $$

and similarly $F(x_2) = 0$ since we have two identical rows, thus by $\mathbf{rolle's}$ there must be a point $c \in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $F'(c) = 0$

Is this a correct argument? I mean, it seems very simple, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aruments are correct. It is simple ! I miss nothing .